# python pycharm (using pyshark library)

Tags: python

How can I add a pcap file to my project files on pycharm ?

Here is my code:

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture('dnpdataset')


def print_conversation_header(pkt):
    try:
        protocol = pkt.transport_layer
        src_addr = pkt.ip.src
        src_port = pkt[pkt.transport_layer].srcport
        dst_addr = pkt.ip.dst
        dst_port = pkt[pkt.transport_layer].dstport
        print
        '%s  %s:%s --> %s:%s' % (protocol, src_addr, src_port, dst_addr, dst_port)
    except AttributeError as e:
        # ignore packets that aren't TCP/UDP or IPv4
        pass

cap.apply_on_packets(print_conversation_header, timeout=100)
```

giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/mtare/PycharmProjects/moe1/first.py", line 3, in 
>       cap = pyshark.FileCapture('dnpdataset')   File "C:\Users\mtare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\file_capture.py",
>   line 47, in **init**
>       raise FileNotFoundError(str(self.input_filename)) FileNotFoundError: dnpdataset

Answer (score 1):

You have to give absolute path of capture file for FileCapture

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture(r'C:\Temp\dnpdataset.pcap')


def print_conversation_header(pkt):
    try:
        protocol = pkt.transport_layer
        src_addr = pkt.ip.src
        src_port = pkt[pkt.transport_layer].srcport
        dst_addr = pkt.ip.dst
        dst_port = pkt[pkt.transport_layer].dstport
        print('%s  %s:%s --> %s:%s' % (protocol, src_addr, src_port, dst_addr, dst_port))
    except AttributeError as e:
        # ignore packets that aren't TCP/UDP or IPv4
        pass


cap.apply_on_packets(print_conversation_header, timeout=100)
```