# python pyshark can't import file — os.path issue?

Tags: python, flask, pyshark

When I try to upload a file that is located in the app folder (app root) I have no issues however, if I want to upload a file that sits outside the app folder, i.e. in the Desktop, then I get the error below.

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370249/python-pycharm-using-pyshark-library) post but it did not help me. Seems like a root scoping issue however, I'm fairly new to Python and I can't seem to find a good solution to fix this.

```
app.root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

target = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'pcap/')

json_target = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/json/')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_pcap():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'file' not in request.files :
            flash('No file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '' :
            flash('No file selected')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            cap = pyshark.FileCapture(filename)

        destination = "".join([target, filename])

        # create folder for pcap file if there is none
        if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)

        # create folder for json file if there is none
        if not os.path.isdir(json_target):
            os.mkdir(json_target)

        print(target)

        for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
            print(file)

            print(destination)

            cap.apply_on_packets(print_conversation_header,timeout=100)
            print(pcap_list[8])

            with open('static/json/data.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(pcap_list, outfile)

                file.save(destination)
                #file.save(os.path.join([target, filename])

        return redirect(url_for('upload_pcap', filename=filename))

return render_template('upload.html', data=pcap_list)
```

The stack trace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File"/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/pcap.py", line 67, in upload_pcap
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture(filename)
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/file_capture.py", line 48, in __init__
    raise FileNotFoundError(str(self.input_filename))
FileNotFoundError: this_angler.pcap
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 13:28:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: this_angler.pcap` seems that you have a file in the current dir, but the current dir isn't the one you think it is.

Comment: I think the path that is given to the file upon upload is posting to the app root and not to the directory root for that file. I tried doing something like `cap = pyshark.FileCapture(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename)))` to pass the absolute path to pyshark however it won't work. Pyshark needs an absolute path, in this case the path has to be the one for that file I'm uploading.

Comment: using the variable `filename` or using `file` return the same error.